# Using ODBC to select from a CSV file with spaces in column names

Tags: c#, sql, csv, odbc

I'm using `ODBC` to to query from a `CSV` file. The `CSV` file contains column names (1st row of `CSV` file), some of which have spaces in them.

I'm using C# to execute the query (a SQL SELECT statement) using the `OdbcCommand` object

If I do nothing, I get an ODBC error, `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[column name here]'` ([column name here] means it just puts in the name of the first column with spaces in it).

I've tried wrapping column names in square brackets, ala SQL Server, but no dice. I've tried double quote, I've tried the back quote. I've tried the apostrophe.

If I use any of these, I get an error saying `Too few parameters. Expected X` where X is either 1 or 3, depending on the wrapping character.

I can't seem to find anything that specifies how to do this in CSV files.

It works fine for CSV files with no spaces in the column name.

**Update 1:** According to this Microsoft page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353(v=vs.85).aspx
Under the `remarks` section for the column name it says, "The text name of the column. If the column name contains embedded spaces, you must enclose it in double quotation marks." I have tried that, as mentioned. Didn't work.

According to this Microsoft page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711819(v=vs.85).aspx
It says, "If column names contain any characters except letters, numbers, and underscores, the name must be delimited by enclosing it in back quotes (`)." Tried. Didn't work.

I am using the Microsoft Text Driver (according to the User DSN page of the ODBC Data Source Administrator), but I don't see it listed on the ODBC Drivers page. On that page, I see SQL Server, SQL Server Native Client and ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server (Version 2015.130.900.73).

Comment: Why not use a System.IO StreamReader ? It works fine, I can give you the code to do so (fully tested to work) if you want - for CSV files.

Comment: @KyleE4K Would your code let me execute a SQL query against a CSV file?

Comment: It isn't ODBC neither SQL primitive, it simply just reads each column and stores them as rows just like a select statement would. You could then add your SQL on-top of it?

Comment: @KyleE4K I need something that I can execute SQL against. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tired using the `REPLACE()` in your SQL query for spaces? Never seen this bahaviour before, show us your code? I voted up for you

Comment: I'd rather not have to write preprocessing code for this and I'd rather not have to modify the CSV file, if possible. I can't just willy-nilly rename columns. For example, what if there's two columns: "NAME S" and "NAMES"? If I try to rename "NAME S" to NAMES, I now have two columns with the same name. Unlikely, I'll grant you, but the code is meant to generically work with a variety of CSV files, so I can't really make assumptions like that. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: Show your code, including the SQL and an example of the CSV. Its tough to find errors when we don't even know what you're doing.

Comment: @mbrig With respect, I described exactly what I'm doing. It's a simple select query listing columns. I don't see how knowing the actual columns names is going to make a difference. If the column names have spaces it doesn't work. If they don't have spaces, it works. In SQL Server, you use square brackets around the column name to deal with this. For Access databases under ODBC, you use back quotes. Presumably there's an equivalent for CSV files under ODBC. That's what I'm trying to determine.

Comment: @Pete and you're using what driver (JET OLE, Microsoft Text)? With what connection string options? Debugging questions are supposed to include an MCVE so that people don't have to guess about this stuff.

Comment: @mbrig I'm using the Microsoft Text driver. Connection string is DSN=VendorList. VendorList is the name of the DSN that I created with" Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv)". And that wouldn't have been in the code. It comes from a config file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a sample I created that works fine. I'm not using a DSN, but it gives you an idea.

#### Data Source (sampledata.csv)

> COLUMN 1,COLUMN 2,COLUMN 3
>   Some value,3,0.01
>   Another value,1,1.2
>   Yet again,2,3

#### schema.ini

> [sampledata.csv]
>   Format=CSVDelimited
>   ColNameHeader=True
>   Col1 = "COLUMN 1" Text
>   Col2 = "COLUMN 2" Long
>   Col3 = "COLUMN 3" Currency

#### The code

```
     string filePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
     string fileName = "sampledata.csv";
     string query = string.Empty;

     //query = "SELECT * FROM " + fileName;
     //query = "SELECT * FROM " + fileName + " WHERE [COLUMN 2] > 1";
     query = "SELECT * FROM " + fileName + " WHERE [COLUMN 3] > 0.02";

     // 32-bit
     // OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver=Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" + filePath + ";Extensions=csv;");
     // 64-bit
     OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection("Driver=Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt, *.csv);Dbq=" + filePath + ";Extensions=csv;");
     conn.Open();
     OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(query, conn);
     OdbcDataAdapter adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(cmd);
     DataSet mydata = new DataSet("CSVData");
     adapter.Fill(mydata);
     conn.Close();
     conn.Dispose();

     dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
     dataGridView1.DataSource = mydata;
     dataGridView1.DataMember = mydata.Tables[0].ToString();
```

In the schema.ini, quotation marks are used around the column name. In the query, brackets are used like a regular SQL statement.

Each of the queries loaded the data as expected in the grid.